# Split using regex

Tags: java, regex, split

Trying to build a search criteria query parsing using StringTokenizer.
The query goes like
`(key:operator:value)`
`(key:operator:value) and (key:operator:value)`

I have tried

```
Stack<Object> stack = new Stack<>();
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(filterString, "()", true);

while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();

    if (isOpenBrace(token)) {
        stack.push(token);
    } else if (isCloseBrace(token)) {
        Object preVal = null;
        Criteria criteria = null;
        String operator = null;

        while (!isOpenBrace(stack.peek())) {
            Object top = stack.pop();

            if (isString(top)) {
                String op = (String) top;

                if (isAnd(op) || isOr(op)) {
                    operator = (String) top;
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid operand");
                }
            } else if (isCriteria(top)) {
                if (preVal != null) {
                    if (isAnd(operator)) {
                        top = ((Criteria) top).and((Criteria) preVal);
                        criteria = (Criteria) top;
                        preVal = top;
                    } else if (isOr(operator)) {
                        top = ((Criteria) top).or((Criteria) preVal);
                        criteria = (Criteria) top;
                        preVal = top;
                    }
                } else {
                    preVal = top;
                    criteria = (Criteria) preVal;
                }
            }
        }

        if (criteria != null) {
            stack.pop();
            stack.push(criteria);
        }
    } else if (isAnd(token) || isOr(token)) {
        stack.push(token);
    } else {
        String[] parts = token.split(COLON);
        // do rest stuffs
}

if (stack.size() != 1) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid filter");
}
```

`Note:` The Criteria internal specific.

This works fine as long as there are no `()` in the value part of the expression.

Im trying to convert the same using `split()` and regexes so that, the tokens I get is

```
"(", "key:operator:va(lue)", ")" for string "(key:operator:va(lue)"
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you should be using regex for this.  A parser, what you already have, seems more appropriate.

Comment: Is there a way to split based on this regex like "string:string:string" which splits on this regex and all the other characters

Comment: Hardly a chance to get it right with nested parenthesis and regex.

Comment: With regex you would not be able to count, and espeically if tokens can have similar start characters this will get unmaintainable pretty fast. Have a look at https://www.antlr.org/